# Why my TableLayout isn't allowed to be inflated?

Tags: android, layout

For a widget I use a simple layout which contains a TableLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow >
         (...)
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

But when a I want to update its content by creating a `RemoteViews`

```
RemoteViews eventElementLayout = new RemoteViews( this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_events_element );
```

I got an exception telling me that `TableLayout` is not allowed to be inflated.

```
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.TableLayout
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:930)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.widget.RemoteViews$ViewGroupAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:513)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:955)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:932)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:219)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:250)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:73)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Class not allowed to be inflated android.widget.TableLayout
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.failNotAllowed(LayoutInflater.java:525)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:472)
12-04 01:36:12.548: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(195):     ... 19 more
```

Why ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

App widgets only allow limited list of layout and view widget types that can be used within them. It looks like `TableLayout` isn't supported. From Google developers [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout):

> A RemoteViews object (and,
>   consequently, an App Widget) can
>   support the following layout classes:
>
> ```
> * FrameLayout
> * LinearLayout
> * RelativeLayout
> ```
>
> And the following widget classes:
>
> ```
> * AnalogClock
> * Button
> * Chronometer
> * ImageButton
> * ImageView
> * ProgressBar
> * TextView
> ```
>
> Descendants of these classes are not supported.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I missed this part of the documentation !