# how to add linebreak in android 2.2 notification

Tags: android

i want to include line breaks in the long text of notifications. \n
does not work.

```
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message+"\r\n"+"test",intent);
```

what is the code for the line break in the android2.2 notification  ?

Thanks

Comment: You may not be able to.  See this similar question:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357450/android-multiline-notifications-notifications-with-longer-text>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have to create a custom notification layout with two text views, each for a line.

Here's the official tutorial for notifications, I am not sure how much of it applies to 2.2 though.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

The following link might be useful too:
[Custom notification layouts and text colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867338/custom-notification-layouts-and-text-colors)