# How can I change the style of a GCM Push Notification

Tags: android, delphi, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firemonkey

I'd like to change style of the GCM Push Notifications my app is receiving from the standard single line notification to a multi-line notification.

The solution from the Java world seems to be to set the style of the notification to `BigTextStyle` when it gets created.

I've found a solution for Local Notifications that involves hacking `Androidapi.JNI.Support.pas` and `System.Android.Notification.pas` so that
`NotificationBuilder` has it's style set to `BigTextStyle`.

I don't see anything analogous to Notification Builder for GCM Push Notifications. What am I missing?

In this case the app is being built for Android using Firemonkey with Delphi 10 (Seattle).

Comment: You can post a feature request.

Comment: I could, but I'd like to do this today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is, if you want to do this you would have to alter the `FMX.jar` that's being deployed with the app.

You'd have to alter the `buildNotification` method of the `com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationPublisher` class.

Source code for the FMX.jar is not distributed with RAD studio, etc. ; so your option is to decompile `FMX.jar`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16470846/685) will give you a foothold on how to modify `buildNotification`. Effectively you'll add the following before the `return`.

```
mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(myVeryLongGCMMessage));
```