# Notification text is too long and is not showing full text

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing an application for android 2.3.3. I am showing a notification but the text of this notification is too long and its not showing the full text and its being cut so how can I show my full text in my notification?

Here's the code:

```
String message = "Tonights Taraweeh consists of Alif Lam Mim and the first quarter of Sayaqul. The Surahs covered are Al-Fatiha(The Opening),and the first two-thirds of Al-Baqara(The Cow).";
Notification notification = new Notification();
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: You must provide your code for us to be able to help you

Comment: [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6357450/2345913)

Comment: yep, please show Your relevant part of code. Did You show via Toast? If Yes, showing long text on Toasts is no good practise because Toasts could be finished by the user if he is touching the screen anywhere. This could happens without intention by the user. An AlertDialog is the better solution

Comment: +1 @CRUSADER pointing out a solution. This unfortunately shows that people search in a bad way for their answers as such questions have already been answered.

Comment: I dont think that 2.3.3 supports long texts

Comment: .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(___big text___))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanded notifications are only available from Android 4.1, [read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Android 2.3.3 uses the old notifications without expansion. You must user a shorter text, cut your text (and show the full text when user click on it) or adapt the text if you are showing the notification in Android 4.1 or older.

Answer (score 5):

I short you have to set the `BigTextStyle`

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
            .setContentTitle(emailObject.getSenderName())
            .setContentText(emailObject.getSubject())
            .setLargeIcon(emailObject.getSenderAvatar())
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(__BigTextHere___))
            .build();
```