# Android ICS Notification with Multi Text update?

Tags: android, notifications

aim trying to send notification with Multi text or multi lines i've success this step 
but when i've tried to update notification text its wont update

how i can update notification text ?

this is my code

```
Intent intent         = new Intent(this, text.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle(foruminfo.forum_title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.add_replay)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(text)) 
        .setAutoCancel(true).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(123123, n);
```

i am new with android i am using the above code inside function and the `text` content multi lines

any advice ? thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see it.

[Android multiline notifications / notifications with longer text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357450/android-multiline-notifications-notifications-with-longer-text)

This link helps notification multiple lines in ICS or earlier.

Comment: please dont just post the link, also post the relevant parts in the message itself